# Retriving JSON with Javascript include, why difference between time required for JS download and JS Execution starts

Tags: javascript, json, eval

I am doing optimization of web app, where I get list data in JSON format in as large size as 1000 objects containing 100s of attributes. eval used to take lot of time to parse this large data. So after digging internet and stackoverflow for some time I got another way of retrieving JSON data from server '**Dynamic Javascript include**'.

Javascript include does JSON parsing very fast, as stated in blogs.(verified with console logs in fiebug). But there is difference between the time Javascript has finished downloading and execution of the script, and huge one as high as 6 to 7 sec. 
Any idea, why this is happening and any ways to resolve this?

Comment: "...eval..." - You know of the native JSON Object, do you?

Comment: No I dont, after some googling I found out that, there is native JSON object of which parse method does JSON parsing faster. But 1 more problem, I am using mootools, which overrides this JSON object and adds its method JSON.decode() which uses nothing else than eval.Any ways with which I can get my native JSON object back with having mootools together.

Comment: By looking at the source it's clear that mootools does in fact ***not*** override the native JSON object https://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/blob/master/Source/Utilities/JSON.js#L19 You need to use `JSON.parse()` to convert the strings into objects etc.

Comment: This is from mootools documentation, and I also checked with source code , there is no parse function in JSON object of mootools. http://mootools.net/docs/core/Utilities/JSON. Using 1.2 version of mootools. Maybe the link provided by you of later version. But I cant change to new version right now, is there any way I can get my native JSON object back with mootools running simultaneously.

Comment: After more googling also found out that native JSON object support is not there for all browsers, all versions right now. Only for IE 8 and Firefox 3.5 above... So that's not a solution for my problem. Btw I found out that this problem is there only for my machine firefox. maybe too many firefox addons making it do so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question here, After more digging I found out that the problem was only replicable on my machine, And on others machine the difference between the mentioned process was very less, So guessing that this may be happening because of too many Firefox addons that I have used.
Just a guess work. not sure yet.